# How to use interrupt()

Tags: java, interrupt

I am using Java to make a game, but I can't use the interrupt() function. It says the interrupt() function is undefined.

Here is the code. What should I do to solve this problem?

p.s. I think somebody says that the error is because of (skip), but I think you didn't catch the meaning of the question.

I found the error. Thanks for the comment!

```
package beat_the_beat_1_0;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class Music {

    private Player player;
    private boolean isLoop;
    private File file;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private BufferedInputStream bis;

    public Music(String name, boolean isLoop) {
        try {
            this.isLoop = isLoop;
            file = new File(Main.class.getResource("../music/" + name).toURI());
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            player = new Player(bis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public int getTime() {
        if(player == null)
            return 0;
        return player.getPosition();
    }

    public void close() {
        isLoop = false;
        player.close();
        this.interrupt(); // Here is the error.
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            do {
                player.play();
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                player = new Player(bis);
            } while(isLoop);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no JavaScript anywhere in that code of yours.

Comment: It's a method of the Thread class, and you're not calling the method on a Thread object.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the call to `this.interrupt()`?  Perhaps all you need to do is replace the call with the assignment `isLoop = false` so the `run()` method will exit.

Comment: I found the reason! At "public class Music {" I had to add "extends Thread".

Comment: Btw it should be unnecessary for a thread to interrupt itself. This doesn’t make sense.